# Algorithm for locking based on a shared resource (dictionary)

Tags: algorithms, concurrency

I am working with a shared resource with the following specifications

- acts as a dictionary (values can be obtained with key name: `dictionary['key']`)
- does not have builtin system for locking
- Multiple threads can read and write to same keys (simple writes and reads are atomic)
- I am trying to implement locking based on keys in that resource using one or more keys in the dictionary as locks with which the threads can obtain a lock for the shared resource. For example:

  - `dictionary['lock'] == null` would mean that the lock has not been obtained.
  - `dictionary['lock'] = myThreadId` would obtain the lock
  - `dictionary['lock'] == myThreadId` would mean the lock is reserved

As far as I know using only one key would not work (see below). I came up with the following 2-part lock solution and the question is: **is there an official name for this kind of solution and could the algorithm be simplified? Or are there any (fatal) flaws in this solution?** Some issues might occur when freeing the locks if another thread has previously been able to enter through the 1st lock.

### Lock using one key

```
Thread reads lock (value in dictionary['lock'])
Thread writes lock
Thread 1 reads lock (to ensure successful write)
```

but that could fail with:

```
Thread 1 reads lock
Thread 2 reads lock
Thread 1 writes lock
Thread 1 reads lock (value "thread1")
Thread 2 writes lock
Thread 2 reads lock (value "thread2")
```

### 2-part lock

I figured having locking with two parts should fix the issue:

```
Step1: READ LOCKS1+2 (reading LOCK2 might not be necessary)
Step2: WRITE LOCK1
Step3: READ LOCK2
Step4: WRITE LOCK2
Step5: READ LOCKS1+2 (reading LOCK2 might not be necessary)
Step5: READ LOCKS1+2 (reading LOCK2 might not be necessary)
```

if two concurrent threads try to obtain the lock, the lock can be recognized as being in a "dirty" state

```
A Step1: READ1+2 => empty+empty
B Step1: READ1+2 => empty+empty
A Step2: WRITE1 => A
A Step3: READ2 => empty
B Step2: WRITE1 => B
B Step3: READ2 => empty
A Step4: WRITE2 => A
A Step5: READ1+2 => B+A !! DIRTY STATE - WAIT
B Step4: WRITE2 => B
A Step5(again): READ1+2 => B+B !! LOCK LOST
B Step5: READ1+2 => B+B
```

likewise:

```
A Step1: READ1+2 => empty+empty
B Step1: READ1+2 => empty+empty
A Step2: WRITE1 => A
A Step3: READ2 => empty
A Step4: WRITE2 => A
A Step5: READ1+2 => A+A
B Step2: WRITE1 => B
B Step3: READ2 => A !! LOCK RESERVED, RESTORE LOCK1 AND CANCEL
```

3rd case:

```
A Step1: READ1+2 => empty+empty
B Step1: READ1+2 => empty+empty
A Step2: WRITE1 => A
A Step3: READ2 => empty
A Step4: WRITE2 => A
B Step2: WRITE1 => B
A Step5: READ1+2 => B+A !! DIRTY STATE - WAIT
B Step3: READ2 => A !! LOCK RESERVED, RESTORY LOCK1 AND CANCEL
A Step5: READ1+2 => A+A !! LOCK1 RESTORED BY B, CONTINUE
```

The code would look something like this:

```
if( lock1.IsFree() && lock2.IsFree() )
{
    lock1.LockForCurrentThread();
    if( lock2.IsFree() )
    {
        lock2.LockForCurrentThread();
        if( lock1.IsLockedByCurrentThread() && lock2.IsLockedByCurrentThread() )
        {
            // OBTAINED
        }
        else
        {
            // Locks not obtained, wait until 1st lock freed or another thread takes the second lock.
            while( lock1.IsLocked() && lock1.IsLockedByCurrentThread() == false && lock2.IsLockedByCurrentThread() )
            {
            }

            // 1st lock is restored to this thread.
            if( lock1.IsLockedByCurrentThread() )
            {
                // OBTAINED
            }
            else // another thread has "stolen" the 2nd lock
            {
                // NOT OBTAINED
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Another thread already has 2nd lock, let's restore it to 1st lock and cancel.
        lock1.Lock( lock2.GetCurrentLockingId() );
        
        // NOT OBTAINED
    }
}
else
{
    // NOT OBTAINED
}
```